# Calling a method containing a Thread from an AsyncTask (don't want to call Looper.prepare())

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have an `AsyncTask` which calls my `LocationHandler` class method `getLocation()` which runs a `Thread` as well. I'm getting the following error:

```
Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Some answers have included calling `Looper` related methods but I'd rather not do this as it's bad practise

Main Activity calls the AsyncTask:

```
public class Main extends Activity {        
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        StartProcess sProcess = new StartProcess();
        sProcess.execute(this);
    }
}
```

AsyncTask:

```
public class StartProcess extends AsyncTask<Main, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Main... params) {
        LocationHandler lh = new LocationHandler();
        try {
            lh.getLocation(null, params[0]);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

LocationHandler, seems to crash when it calls `requestLocationUpdates`():

```
public class LocationHandler {
    LocationManager mlocManager;
    MyLocationListener mlocListener;
    Location location;

    public synchronized void getLocation(final View view, final Main main) throws InterruptedException
    {   
        mlocManager = (LocationManager)main.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
            Looper.prepare();
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 1, mlocListener);
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 1, mlocListener);


        Thread uiThread = new HandlerThread("UIHandler"){
            public synchronized void run(){

                //stuff
                }

            }

        };
        uiThread.start();

    }
```

LocationListener:

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {

        location = new Location(loc);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used @nininho suggestion but I called `Looper.prepare()` just before I called `requestLocationUpdates()` in my `LocationHandler` class. I also had to call `Looper.loop()` just after I called the `Thread` otherwise the `Thread` wouldn't even run.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if I do it right, but in one of my function I just add something like this:
 mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
, and it helped.

Comment: I'm really not sure about it, maybe try to do something with your HandlerThread ?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the HandlerThread that the compiler is complaining, just call Looper.prepare() before using the HandlerThread

Comment: This is correct, but make sure you only call Looper.prepare() once on that thread, else it will error.

Comment: Thanks, I called `Looper.prepare()` just before the `requestLocationUpdates()` (doesnt work anywhere else), and that still didn't work so I added `Looper.loop()` after `uiThread.start()` as well and then it started working.